# My metroframework form becomes a new form after cleaning and rebuilding my solution now all the components are gone

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2013, metroframework

I was dealing with this error **"the type namespace 'Resource' could not be found".**

So after adding some reference for that I got the run-time designer error like that with the title **"to prevent any data loss resolve the following error first"** (didn't take it seriously ). I cleaned and rebuild the solution and then my form became a completely new form without any components on it although the back end code is all there except for the warnings in `designer.cs` in which all form components are declared but it says them as warning **"the field metrolabel1 is never used"** it says that about all the components that were there before on the form.

I am stuck on this situation. Is there any way I can get my design layout code back?

Comment: Is this question about WinForms or WPF? Please remove one of the wrong tags.

Comment: it is Wpf form but with metro framework UI. i thought that this kind or error dont have to do anything with the framework. it might also occur in WPF forms, therefore i added the WPF tags

Comment: No, you shouldn't add tags because you think that some issue _might_ occur somewhere. Instead, you should tag your questions only with those tags that are **relevant** for **your particular question**.

Comment: okay i understand but Can you help me though?